# About negative binomial regression in large data

Tags: r, large-data

I have a data about 19 columns and more than 10 million rows. Now I want to run negative binomial regression.

Since the memory is the bottleneck, I planed to use `ff` package to deal with the issue. But it turned out that the function `glm.nb` in `MASS` package cannot be used in this case. And there's a `ffbase` package, which have some enhanced functions, but without glm.nb.

Also`bigmemory` and `biganalytics`packages have such problems.

I don't know whether my understanding is correct. Or there's indeed a feasible way to incorporate `ff` and `MASS`. So how to proceed in the next?

PS, I use windows...which seems to be a curse dealing with such large data..

Any link, comments, or tips are appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Windows and how much memory? 32-bit Windows 7 will only recognise about 3GB regardless of how much RAM is installed but the 64-bit version doesn't have this limitation. Web services such as Amazon EC2 offer cheap computing power if you can't find an alternative solution for your own system.

Comment: Matt Weller， thanks for your comments. I have 8 Gb Ram and 64bit windows. But it seems that the memory is not enough though...

Comment: Maybe ask the author of the MASS package (Brian Ripley) to allow glm.nb to work on ffdf object. Haven't looked to it in detail but it might be relatively straightforward as the code in glm.nb where it says glm.fitter should be replaced by ffbase::bigglm.ffdf to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Take a random sample of your data points. Do the analysis. Repeat. Estimate the variance due to this monte-carlo process. If your resulting parameters are still significantly non-zero then stop.